# Is there an equivalent of Rob Conery's Massive for NoSQL (MongoDB)?

Tags: c#, mongodb, massive

Is there an equivalent of Rob Conery's Massive for NoSQL (MongoDB)?

I like [Massive](https://github.com/robconery/massive) very much, but I'd like to use it with NoSQL databases, especially with MongoDB and I can't find a decent alternative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are interested in the 'single file' aspects of it then it shouldn't be too hard to create something using the Bson serializer / deserializer code provided in the MongoDB driver to store Bson documents in the file system.

If you are interested in the query aspects of it, SQL isn't the right language to query a document store like MongoDB.

And finally, if you are interested in the dynamic aspects of it, well the closest I've found to that so far is [my own blog post on using dynamic objects with MongoDB](http://blog.abodit.com/2011/09/dynamic-persistence-with-mongodb-look-no-classes-polymorphism-in-c/).

Comment: Great work on MongoDynamic, looking forward to trying this out.

Comment: Indeed that's what I was looking for, the dynamic aspect of Massive is just full of awesomeness. I'll take a look at your blog, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Simple.Data has an adapter for MongoDB - https://github.com/markrendle/Simple.Data

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't get it (but I'm not a NoSQL guru by any means):

The point of Massive is to map a relational database table to an object.
The point of NoSQL is that there are no relational database tables, but that you save your objects directly into the database instead.

So...what feature of Massive do you want to use with a NoSQL DB?
Do you really need a Massive equivalent for NoSQL?

Comment: I'm guessing it's more the dynamic aspect Massive, of mapping things from a database to C# dynamic objects, whether they're BSON documents in MongoDB or rows from a SQL Server table.  Currently the C# driver allows mapping to POCOs, but not to dynamic types yet.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. As I said, I'm no NoSQL guru. I was just wondering, based on my little NoSQL knowledge.

Comment: Yes, the dynamics is what I was looking for